# Get ANSI-colored output from external command

Tags: ruby, ansi-colors

I am writing a small script for `watchr` that runs my PHP unit tests.

Current script runs tests using `system()` and displays them colored.

I am trying to add `libnotify` functionality, but for that I need to parse the output and match against regexp, so that notification will either display green or red.

`system()` doesn't return output, `%x` does return, but `puts p` doesn't display colors, which I need to quickly see which test failed. One option would be to run tests twice - once for display in terminal window, and second time for checking which notification to show, but I would rather avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`puts` does display colors. The problem is when you run with `%x` your PHP test runner will most likely turn off colored output because it thinks it's not running under a terminal.

The same thing happens if you do `run_php_test | less` in the shell. To fix it you need to force colored output on the PHP test runner.

**EDIT**

Easiest way to run a subprocess with `pty`:

```
require 'pty'
puts PTY.spawn('run_php_test')[0].read
```

Comment: Is there a way to trick external command into thinking that it's running under terminal that supports colors? I checked test runner's options - there's no way to force colored output.

Comment: If there's a way for it to run with coloring off, there should be a way to turn it on, right? So somewhere in the test runner code it's turning coloring on or off. Maybe there's no direct command-line switch for it, but there is code in there somewhere for it. Perhaps you can monkey patch it. However if that's not an option you could try the `pty` library in ruby. It runs processes in a virtual terminal. See method #7 here: http://devver.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/ruby-subprocesses-part_3/